# EF4 - Self tracking entities and inheritance and eager loading

Tags: entity-framework-4

I know this has been asked before in several ways but none of the answers seem applicable to me - or correct - or current, so I'll try again.

I have a large model with several intstances of inherited entities.  One example is a Timetable that contains a collection of TimetableEvents.  There are several sub-types of TimetableEvent, such as an InterviewTimetableEvent, BreakTimetableEvent and an ExercisetimeTableEvent.  ExerciseTimetableEvent has a relationship to an Exercise entity.

I need to use self-tracking entities as I'm using a WCF back end to serve up data to several WPF clients in a stateless fashion.

So, I need to eager load everything and I thought that self-tracking entities would automatically do this but it appears they dont.

So, to get a timetable I need to do something like this:

```
            var tt = (from s in ESSDataContainer.Timetables
                   .Include("TimetableEvents")
                  where s.TimetableId == timetableid
                  select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will give me the TimetableEvents but not the Exercises that are related to the ExerciseTimetableEvents.  Ive tried the following (and several other suggestions) without luck:

```
            var tt = (from s in ESSDataContainer.Timetables
                   .Include("TimetableEvents")
                   .Include("ExerciseTimetableEvents.Exercise")
                  where s.TimetableId == timetableid
                  select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a solution to this?

If not I'll go back to normal context tracking and connect to the database from a local container rather than using WCF.

Cheers

Comment: As a side note I'd just like to add that after several attempts over many years to make data access easy and simple, Microsoft (and pretty much everyone else) has failed miserably!  This is always way harder than it should be.  There should be a Nobel prize for this... then we might see something truly easy to use!

Comment: Be careful when making a statement like that, you will cause a riot here. And with your Q, i've had the same problem. You can't eager load a derived relationship because you don't know what it type it is yet. Only solutions i've found is move the navs up to the parent, or 2 database calls.

Comment: @RPM1984 See my answer for a solution without schema changes or multiple calls.

Comment: Bring on the flamers - I'm up for it! :)  Less is more but not enough is worse.  We need to get to the point where we don't know or care about how or where the objects are stored - currently we are only half way there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but possible:

```
var tt = (from s in ESSDataContainer.Timetables
          where s.TimetableId == timetableid
          select new 
          {
              TimeTable = s,
              Events = s.TimeTableEvents,
              Exercise = s.TimeTableEvents.OfType<ExerciseTimetableEvents>()
                                          .Select(ett => ett.Exercise)
          }).Select(s => s.TimeTable)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Clear as mud, but, hey: No magic strings! Also, it has the advantage that it actually works....

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I can now see how this works and why it's necessary, but gee, it's ugly having to do that.  I'm not keen on doing this across the whole schema though so Ive reverted back to container tracking and have the data layer connecting to sql from each client rather than having a wcf service for it.  It's a shame but budget and time have runout to fix this now.

Comment: Nice one +1. I've read it three times now and still don't understand it. :) @Craig Stuntz - can you look at an earlier Q i posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011211/entity-framework-4-abstract-model-how-to-programatically-eager-load-navigationa And see if this can be applied to mine? Would really appreciate it. I think my scenario is a little more tricky.

Comment: @RPM1984, I don't think I'd do this in the case where I don't know what type is coming back.

Comment: Yep, that how my problem was different. :( At the moment i'm looking at TPH, if that doesn't work i'll have to stick with 2 calls. Thanks for looking anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Proposal for this issua at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594289/in-entity-framework-there-should-be-a-way-to-eager-load-include-navigation-properties-of-a-derived-class):. If you think this worthy you can vote for it.